# How to send POST request with x-www-for-urlencoded body in JMeter?

Tags: rest, http-headers, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

How can I send POST requests with `x-www-form-urlencoded` body in JMeter?

It's working in Postman. I have tried using HTTP Header Manager with `Content-Type` set to `x-www-form-urlencoded` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but I still face the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If your request works fine in Postman you should be able to use JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Prepare JMeter for recording. The fastest and the easiest way is using [JMeter Templates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature/) feature

   - from JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"

     [image]
   - open HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and click "Start"

     [image]
2. Prepare Postman for recording.

   - from Postman's main menu choose [`File -> Settings -> Proxy`](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/proxy/)
   - Use `127.0.0.1` as the "Proxy Server" and `8888` as the port

     [image]
3. Execute the request in Postman
4. JMeter should capture the request and store it under Thread Group -> [Recording Controler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)

See [Apache JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) article for more information if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I had to check off the "**Use multipart/form-data**" option in the HTTP Request to make it work, and then add the form parameters in the "Parameters" tab:
[image]